# Rvest Unable to Webscrape Certain Site

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

Trying to create an application in R that returns search data from the following website:

https://www.gsaadvantage.gov/advantage/main/start_page.do

and then perform necessary analysis of data. I am using the "rvest" package, and the website's formatting is nearly impossible to work with. For example, something similar to the following method works on other websites, but something about this site is causing problems:

```
library('rvest')
url <-"https://www.gsaadvantage.gov/advantage/s/search.do?s=0&c=100&q=0:2mouse+pad&searchType=1&p=1"

data <- read_html(url) %>%
    html_nodes('.arial strong') %>%
    html_text()
```

IS there something we're doing wrong, and is there a better package for use on the GSA website. Thank you!

Comment: Did you mean to add a `%>%` between the last two calls?  Otherwise, I'm not sure why the search yields `404`

Comment: In addition to the missing `%>%`, your url seems to be invalid

Comment: Yesterday that url was buggy, but worked fine. Now it doesn't seem to be working. The previous problem we were encountering was not with accessing the site, but now we have that problem too. I updated the code with the following url: https://www.gsaadvantage.gov/advantage/s/search.do?s=0&c=100&q=0:2mouse+pad&searchType=1&p=1